# Stripe React Firebase: Wrong sessionId with stripe checkoutSession. I can't receive this sessionId

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am trying create a subscription using Stripe Firebase Extension.
I am writing on JS, using the guide

**Here is the code in guide**
[Guide page](https://docs.react2025.com/payments/checkout)

```
After creating the Checkout session, the Stripe Firebase extension will populate the sessionId on the document, which allows you to redirect to the Checkout.
lib/db.js
import firebase from './firebase';
import getStripe from './stripe';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid) {
  const checkoutSessionRef = await firestore
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('checkout_sessions')
    .add({
      price: 'price_HLxRKYrVN3CVzy',
      // This can be removed if you don't want promo codes
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      success_url: window.location.origin,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin
    });

  checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
    const { sessionId } = snap.data();

    if (sessionId) {
      const stripe = await getStripe();

      stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
    }
  });
}
```

I am already curious, cause the code the looks like node or next...
Me version of code

**createCheckoutSession.js**

```
import { addDoc, doc, onSnapshot, collection } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { firestore } from "../../firebase";
import { getStripe } from "./initializeStripe";

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid) {

  const stripe = await getStripe();

  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "users", `${uid}`, "checkout_sessions"), {
    price: "PRICE_ID",
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  })

  // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
  onSnapshot(doc(firestore, "users", `${uid}`, "checkout_sessions", docRef.id), (doc) => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    const { sessionId } = doc.data();
    
    console.log("doc data: ", doc.data());
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: "123"});
  });
}
```

Despite of this changes, which I can't understand, why I am supposed to do it (You can explain, if want), part until

> const { sessionId } = doc.data();

working, here as in guide I'm trying get sessionId from my doc data, but there is no such attribute... So I can't create checkoutSession.

I will be pleasure for any help :)

Maksym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful, when you set up **Stripe Extension**, I changed path from **users** -> **customers**. That is reason, the firebase didn't add stripe extra info.

**So go in Firebase Extensions -> Stripe Extension** and check all paths.
[image]